# How to symbolize AddressSanitizer stacktrace?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-ndk, android-debug, address-sanitizer

With the help of [this](https://virtualrealitypop.com/oreo-ndk-secrets-7d075a9b084) helpful article, I am able to integrate Address Sanitizer into my android application.
I am using x86 debug build on the emulator to find the memory issues my C++ code 
My x86 debug build working and a functional wrap.sh installed on the emulator. Once the APK is installed, the application runs and the app is crashing as soon as AddressSanitizer finds the very first memory issue, and I can see backtrace of the crash via adb logcat.  The stack traces produced by AddressSanitizer are not symbolized, so I have no idea what problem it has found for me.
I am facing the issue in symbolizing stack frame.
I am using NDK Version  17.1.4828580

a) how to symbolize the stacktrace?

b) Is there anyway, AddressSanitizer not to crash the app after finding the very first issue, and proceed further to find and report next issue?

c) As per documentation, however, AddressSanitizer reports memory issues such as overflow, use after return etc, but it doesn't report memory leaks in native code s ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1 is not supported on Android. Is there any tool available which could point memory leaks in native code?

Comment: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/native-memory malloc_debug can be used.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using [ndk-stack](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack).
2. Try halt_on_error=false option, see [this](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/649#issuecomment-176304136)